# How to remove certain characters from an fstream text?

Tags: c++, string, char, fstream

I'm going through an exercise that entails outputting text from a file after removing all the vowels from it. For example, a file containing the text "Theory of Computation" should output "Thry f Cmpttn".

I tried building a function 'removeVowel(ifsream&)' that reads the data from an ifstream and stores it in a string, then add all the non-vowel characters in a new string and return that string.

```
bool isVowel(char ch){

switch (ch) {
case'a':
case'e':
case'i':
case'o':
case'u':
    return true;
}

return false;
}

string removeVowel(ifstream& line){


string ss;

string no_Vow;

while (getline(line, ss)) {

    for (int i = 0; i < ss.size(); i++) {
        if (!isVowel(ss[i]))
            no_Vow += ss[i];
    }
}
return no_Vow;
}

int main() {
string nahmen;
cout << "Enter file name";
cin >> nahmen;

ifstream fs{nahmen};
ofstream fso{ nahmen };

fso << "A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";

string new_s;

new_s = removeVowel(fs);

cout << new_s;

}
```

I expected the the string without vowels to be output in the console, but the program terminates without outputting the string.

Comment: Either you use different input and output file or you read the complete input file into memory before opening the output file with same name. Reading and writing to the same file is not a good idea. The writing resets the file before reading can complete.

Comment: Looking twice, I get the impression that you want to write the file with `"A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"`, then read it and output the processed contents to console. In this case, I would re-order the file output before file input. Furthermore, it cannot hurt to close the output file before opening the input file. (May be, I should even say: You should...)

Comment: @Scheff closing the ofstream worked. Thank You.

Comment: The reason for that is: output streams don't need to write to physical file immediately. They may buffer internally to improve performance. `flush()` is the method to force writing (at least, to OS which may buffer again but this should be invisible on "application level"). However, closing a file forces a `flush()` before. So, it should be done always, and it should be checked for success. Btw. if an output stream instance goes out of scope, it is closed automatically if still open. Hence, putting the output stream with writing into an extra pair of braces (`{ }`) would do as well.

Comment: Also, you *should* change to `switch (tolower(ch))` in any case the letters are upper case...

Answer (score 0):

Your original code will overwrite the input before you are reading it, thus no data to handle. Usually, you don't want to destroy the in data for files, but if you do then you need to store the new file content somewhere. For a smaller file, it can be OK to do this in memory. For larger files, it might be better to store in a temporary file and then move the temporary file over the original input.

Below is an example using the STL to accomplish the task, thus reducing the amount of logic you have to write.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

namespace {
static bool isVowel(char const ch) {
    // '\0' is considered part of the search string, thus need to handle it separately
    return (std::strchr("aeiouAEIOU", ch) != nullptr) && (ch != '\0');
}

static void setOutputExceptions(std::ostream &os) {
    // Set exceptions on this we usually don't want to handle for output strings
    os.exceptions(std::ios_base::badbit | std::ios_base::eofbit | std::ios_base::failbit);
}
}  // close unnamed namespace

int main() {
    setOutputExceptions(std::cout);
    std::cout << "Enter file name: ";

    std::string nahmen;
    std::cin >> nahmen;
    if (!std::cin) throw std::runtime_error("Unable to read file name");

    std::string fileContent;
    {
        std::ifstream fs{nahmen};
        if (!fs) throw std::runtime_error("unable to open file " + nahmen);
        // we do not copy the vowels to fileContent to save space
        remove_copy_if(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fs), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
                       back_inserter(fileContent),
                       isVowel);
    }  // close fs
    // we don't to have a input and output handle to the same file at the same time
    {
        std::ofstream fso;
        setOutputExceptions(fso);
        fso.open(nahmen);
        fso << fileContent;
    }  // close fso
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```